# mercurial merge files missing

Tags: mercurial, merge

I was doing pull with mercurial eclipse plugin. Dialog 'merge with two heads' appeared and it took a long time, nothing was happening, so I clicked again on 'merge with two haeds' but then it wouldn't show files with conflicts in 'Mercurial merge' view. It pulled changes, but can not resolve conflicts. Then I tried to do pull again, 'merge with two heads' appears but this time it says I have uncomitted changes that will be discarded so I said 'No' (I am scared I will lose my previously comitted changes). Can someone please give some advice? What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

You "should" be fine to discard the uncommitted changes; the failed merge would create "uncomitted changesets". I have had to do the same on failed merges before before by using `hg update -C` where the -C means "Clean it up and throw away all changes that aren't committed".

Regarding your fear of losing your committed changes: once you have committed your changes, it is very hard to get rid of them without hg extensions that let you edit history. So you should be safe. (You do have a backup plan in place, right?) If you hadn't committed important changes before you started the merge you only have yourself to blame! :)

To try to sort things out, you could clone the repo to an adjacent location, such as `\repo2\` and verify that it has the changes you expect. You can also attempt the merge in `\repo2\` first and only pull the merged changeset into `\repo\` once it is successful.